# Can spammers use the phone number being called as their spoof number?

Tags: calls, tasker

I originally bought Tasker several (5?) years ago to screen calls by:

1) blocked name/number--hang up

2) not in my contact list

3) family

4) friends (in my contact list but not family or Professionals)

5) Professionals

6) Previously blocked callers
Within the last few days I've received calls which ring in as family and the number is apparently the same as the number being called.  Have you experienced that and is there anything that Tasker can do about it?

Comment: Not much can be done... Spoofing Caller IDs is cery common now and most people use apps that can call online... They Mod the registered number so it will look like yours...

Comment: If you know Exactly Who is doing this, They are abusing the Caller ID Service wich is illegal in my countries... Report them to the relevant Authorities.

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Usually spoofing from the same number is not possible because it causes error's on the MSP end, and they block the weird call .

Comment: I guess I will try checking the calling number against the phone number, even though that seems really weird.   Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It works through overseas Call Redirectors ... You call the overseas call center, you give the number for the ID to use, The server or call center calls the target using the number you specified and then connects the calls together   .. Patches the calls together... It works best like that because the originating number calls an entirely different country and phone in another country... That country has an entirely separate call made out and into the target country... This makes it very hard to follow the call

Comment: If the call were originated overseas, could they specify the spoof number and called number to be the same?  Pretty sure it was a scammer trying to get me to redirect my internet through their server.

Comment: Yes they could however when i tested this for a report a made to my mobile service provider... I never managed to get the call to go through as the same number... It caused a problem on the network that almost worked like an infinite loop, The call never went through... Both ends just keep ringing...

Comment: I realized something after writing this... Whilst testing, i Initiated the call from the target device... Because the person was NOT Initializing the call from your device, You obviously could receive the call that way ( As long as you are not already ON a Call.. )